# Class not found using Namespaces and Autoloader

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

I'm getting a really weird error at the moment that is shown when I try running my PHP code on a server but is not highlighted when viewing the code. It's part of a new project I'm building using Composers for the first time and namespaces, etc. The error is:

```
[18-Apr-2017 20:06:32 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'ThomasSmyth\LoginSystem' not found in /home/thomassm/public_html/php/functions/fncregister.php:4
```

The File Layout:

[image]

LoginSystem.php

```
namespace ThomasSmyth;

class LoginSystem {
    private $core;
    private $builder;
    private $config;

    function __construct(){
        $this->core = new coreFunctions();
        $this->builder = new \NilPortugues\Sql\QueryBuilder\Builder\GenericBuilder();
        $this->config = require('core.config.php');
    }
//...
}
```

fncRegister.php

```
require_once "../../vendor/autoload.php";
$LoginManager = new \ThomasSmyth\LoginSystem();

echo $LoginManager->Register($_POST["StrSurname"], $_POST["StrForename"], $_POST["StrEmail"], $_POST["StrPassword"], $_POST["DteDoB"], $_POST["StrGender"], $_POST["StrToken"]);
```

composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "nilportugues/sql-query-builder": "^1.5"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "ThomasSmyth\\": "php/lib/"
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what might be causing this, whether it being code or server set up?

Comment: sorry, i asked unrelated things earlier.. the one that missing was the LoginSystem. the path and filename is ok, composer ok -- did you run `composer dump-autoload` before trying..? and care to take a peek on the autoload file. perhaps that will shed some light.

Comment: I didn't do the dump, should I try that now? Plus, what should I look for in the autoload file? It's only 2 lines log, but I noticed it has no closing ?> tag, is that ok?

Comment: Why your file has a different icon?

Comment: yes, you should try to dump first. the autoload file contains an array of namespaces paired with paths. also it is ok that it did not have closing tag -- as the entire file is in php.

Comment: @Hackerman PHPStorm recognised it as a class file I think due to the class being the same name as the file. Not sure why it doesn't do the same for the coreFunctions file.

Comment: Maybe you are on a Windows system...and your filename really is `LoginSystem.php.txt`

Comment: @BagusTesa, `composer dump-autoload` seemed to work and I had to adjust something else to get the namespace correctly for `CoreFunctions()`. Now onto the next error... E: Please post it as an answer so I can give you the rep, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although in comment we already solved this problem, i decided to write an answer for this.

The question already have the right file path, namespacing, and composer.json configuration. The only one missing is generating the autoload scripts using `composer dump-autoload`.

This command will make several `autoload*.php` files that contains file path paired with its namespace. As explained in [Composer Website](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload).